# SQL Server - Display columns from multiple rows as single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently my data returns this:

```
invoice_no      rejected_dt    cleared_rejections_dt
1000            2020-10-15     NULL
1000            NULL           2020-10-17
1200            2020-10-20     NULL
1400            2020-10-25     NULL
1200            NULL           2020-10-31
```

I want something like this:

```
invoice_no      rejected_dt    cleared_rejections_dt
1000            2020-10-15     2020-10-17
1200            2020-10-20     2020-10-31
1400            2020-10-25     NULL
```

I've played around with pivots but all my previous values have been aggregate functions, how do I do this with dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  aggregation function and group by

```
    select invoice_no,     max( rejected_dt),     max(cleared_rejections_dt)
    from my_table  
    group by invoice_no
```

Comment: why you try to force someone to accepted your answer?

Comment: @Linker  .. if you don'yt like my answer you can downvote  ..

Comment: Why you give me minus vote can you explain?

Comment: @linker  ... are you sure ...?  .

Comment: your answer is almost correct but not fully correct. And now your are trying to push me down.

Comment: @Linker  ..  the choose for correct answer and for upvote is not mine but is done by the OP and all SO   users .. so ..  you are telling me things that il large part non depending by me

Comment: I get that. But you still you asked for the acceptance from user that where felt that it was wrong.

Comment: The OPcan change the choice when he prefers  ..   this often happen  ..